# Like operator with % in oracle plsql cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I cannot pass the like operator with % in the cursor sql stmt, getting code error, Can you help

```
SQL> l
  1  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE cleanuptab (
  2    isrc_tns VARCHAR2
  3    )
  4  IS
  5  sql_stmt VARCHAR2(500);
  6  errm   VARCHAR2(2000);
  7  refcur   SYS_REFCURSOR;
  8  v_tabs VARCHAR2(50);
  9  BEGIN
 10      OPEN refcur FOR 'SELECT table_name FROM dba_tables where table_name like '%''||isrc_tns||''%' and owner='DBASCHEMA'';
 11      LOOP
 12        BEGIN
 13        FETCH refcur INTO v_tabs;
 14        EXIT WHEN refcur%NOTFOUND;
 15          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table DBASCHEMA.'
 16          ||v_tabs
 17          || ' purge';
 18          dbms_output.Put_line('DROPPED '
 19          ||v_tabs);
 20        EXCEPTION
 21        WHEN OTHERS THEN
 22          dbms_output.Put_line( 'TABLE NOT FOUND: '
 23          ||v_tabs);
 24          CONTINUE;
 25        END;
 26      END LOOP;
 27      close refcur;
 28* END;
SQL> /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show error
Errors for PROCEDURE CLEANUPTAB:

LINE/COL ERROR                                                                  
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------      
10/79    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "%" when expecting one of the        
         following:                                                             
         * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem                       
         <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2           
         like4 likec between using || multiset member submultiset               
         The symbol "* was inserted before "%" to continue.                     
                                                                                
10/96    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "%" when expecting one of the        
         following:                                                             
         * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem                       
         <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2           

LINE/COL ERROR                                                                  
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------      
         like4 likec between using || member submultiset
```

I am trying to pass the like stmt & owner condition so that i can get those tables & drop. Pls help to review

Regards
Kannan

Comment: 1. ref cursor is not needed; the column "table_name" is a fixed length one
2. no need for single quoting twice inside a normal select
3. advice: automating DDL like this could be dangerous

Comment: It would help if you included the full error message in your question. I assume the original code had a `CREATE OR REPLACE` at the beginning. With that fix, the first error message I see is "PLS-00113: END identifier 'CLEANUPORGINTTAB' must match 'CLEANUPTAB' at line 1, column 11", which means you have to use the same name at both the beginning and the end.

Comment: i just editied the code with more error details, Pls review @Nizam Madurai

Comment: I have pasted the full code with error @JonHeller

Comment: @user9599919 There are some issues with escaping the quotation marks. It gets tricky to double all the quotation marks. Coding in an IDE with syntax highlighting can often help with those issues. Try this line: `OPEN refcur FOR 'SELECT table_name FROM dba_tables where table_name like ''%'''||isrc_tns||'''%'' and owner=''DBASCHEMA''';`

Comment: `SQL> 
SQL> EXEC cleanuptab('NA45DB1DFW');
BEGIN cleanuptab('NA45DB1DFW'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at "SYS.CLEANUPTAB", line 8
ORA-06512: at line 1.`

Comment: after i change the code as you suggested I can able to compile the code, but if i execute the code I am getting same code error @JonHeller

Comment: @user9599919 Woops, I forgot to add the concatenation operator. Try this: `OPEN refcur FOR 'SELECT table_name FROM dba_tables where table_name like ''%''||'||isrc_tns||'||''%'' and owner=''DBASCHEMA''';`

Comment: @JonHeller Code compiled, but while executing the code still the same syntax issue on same line ..

Comment: @user9599919 Try this: `OPEN refcur FOR 'SELECT table_name FROM all_tables where table_name like ''%''||'''||isrc_tns||'''||''%'' and owner=''DBASCHEMA''';`

Comment: thanks a lot @JonHeller perfectly working !!

Comment: @user9599919 Are you sure I suggest you print the sql before running it to make sure it's what you need. Looking at the previous comment this may not be the sql you need to run:
 `sql_stmt := 'SELECT table_name FROM dba_tables where table_name like ''%'||isrc_tns||'%'' and owner=''DBASCHEMA''';
 dbms_output.Put_line('SQL is '
         ||sql_stmt);
OPEN refcur FOR sql_stmt;`

Comment: Using @JonHeller's SQL will end up with || characters in the resulting SQL

Comment: This code is probably not run with arbitrary user input. If it was, it would be a prime example for SQL injection. Stop concatenating parameters to SQL statements and executing them.

Comment: This is an extraordinarily dangerous procedure. It could easily wipe out the whole schema, or all tables with a E in the name etc.

Answer (score 4):

Why not try it without OPEN/FETCH/NOTFOUND, without all the local variables, without the danger of SQL injection, with less lines of codes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE cleanuptab (
    isrc_tns VARCHAR2
)
IS
BEGIN
    FOR v_tabs IN (SELECT table_name FROM dba_tables WHERE table_name LIKE '%' || isrc_tns || '%' AND owner = 'DBASCHEMA')
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table DBASCHEMA.' || v_tabs.table_name  || ' purge';
            dbms_output.put_line('DROPPED ' || v_tabs.table_name );
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                dbms_output.put_line('FAILED TO DROP ' || v_tabs.table_name);
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: This is a better approach but that should be `v_tabs.table_name`, also if the table is locked or can't be dropped for some other reason this will display 'TABLE NOT FOUND'.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake re `v_tabs.table_name`. I've fixed it. And yes the message "TABLE NOT FOUND" is shown for a variety of reasons. It's something I've copied from the original code. I've now changed the message even though this might not have been the original intention.